# How to get the new value of a variable in another function after it was changed inside a different function, in Angular ...service.ts

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a service file auth.service.ts

```js
export class AuthService {
  private _isLoggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  isLoggedIn = this._isLoggedIn.asObservable()

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  //if admin
  //setter method
  updateAuthenticated(newValue: boolean){
    this._isLoggedIn.next(newValue);
  }
  
  //for guarding routes
  //getter method
  isAuthenticated(){
    return this.isLoggedIn.subscribe(isLoggedIn =>{
      console.log(isLoggedIn);
    });
  }
```

On calling the updateAuthenticated() method inside the login.component.ts

```js
this.authService.updateAuthenticated(true);
this.route.navigate(['/admin']);
```

Changes made to the variable inside the updateAuthenticated() method are not reflected if I check the variable value in isAuthenticated() method which still remains "false" as initialized. However, Checking the value inside the setter method returns the correct value. I tried using BehaviourSubject and can't get it right. Is there a way to get the new value inside the isAuthenticated() method (getter method) or what am I doing wrong with the BehaviourSubject?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Right now `isAuthenticated`, method isn't a `getter`, it is subscribing to observable. Can you please show a code return inside a guard?

Comment: Yeah, haven't updated it to match with the behavior subject, but this is the code am using to debug  `this.authService.isAuthenticated();` inside the guard.ts @PankajParkar

Comment: Are you using this guard on parent route or child route? If it's on parent route use canActivateChild inspite of canActivate.

Comment: Parent route, `http://localhost:4200/admin` and also using canActivate, thought about using local storage but then that would be insecure @PankajParkar

Comment: Did you use `canActivateChild` instead?

Comment: I am using `canActivate`. I have also tried `canActivateChild`  but also not working. @PankajParkar

Comment: Is this something not working inside lazy loaded module? and which angular version you're using?

Comment: `Angular: 13.3.6`,  haven't enabled that, let me finish integrating it with accesToken (JWT) and see if there is another logic to bypass that. @PankajParkar

Comment: just one thing I can suggest is, does your service has `@Injectable({providerIn: 'root'})` on top of `export class AuthService` and also make sure `AuthService` is not `providers` of AppModule. Otherwise you would have to use `forRoot` pattern for shared module.

Comment: It has `@Injectable..`  as that is generated automatically and also `AuthService` is not ` a `provider` of AppModule. Have you tried regenerating the error? @PankajParka

Comment: @Kennedy TBH, It would be great if you can regenerate the error in stackblitz and give it to me? I'm just keep on guessing based on the code mentioned in question.

Answer (score 0):

The function `isAuthenticated()` inside the service will not emit the value, because it will return you the whole observable instance. You need to subscribe to the observable `isLoggedIn` directly inside the component where you need to listen for the `BehaviorSubject` event.

So instead of putting `isAuthenticated()` is the service.ts file, go the component that needs the emitted value, and do following:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit() {
  latestValue: boolean;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.isLoggedIn.subscribe(isLoggedIn =>{
      this.latestValue = isLoggedIn;
      // now use this.latestValue within the component
    });

  }
}
```